# haystack.exceptions.SearchBackendError: No fields were found in any search_indexes. Please correct this before attempting to search

Tags: django, search, django-haystack

I am trying to implement Haystack with whoosh.

I keep getting this error although everything seems to be configured fine. I get the error:

```
haystack.exceptions.SearchBackendError: No fields were found in any search_indexes. Please correct this before attempting to search.
```

...when I try to do **./manage.py rebuild_index**

configuration:

```
HAYSTACK_SITECONF = 'myproject'
HAYSTACK_SEARCH_ENGINE = 'whoosh'
HAYSTACK_WHOOSH_PATH = cwd + '/whoosh/mysite_index'
```

There are successfully created **whoosh/mysite_index** directories in the root folder of my project.

*search_sites.py*

```
import haystack
haystack.autodiscover()
```

*search_indexes.py*

```
from haystack.indexes import *
from haystack import site
from myproject.models import *

class ResearchersIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = CharFIeld(model_attr='name')

class SubjectIndex(SearchIndex):
    short_name = CharField(model_attr='short_name')
    name = CharField(model_attr='name')
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)

class ResearchIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    abstract = TextField(model_attr='abstract')
    methodology = TextField(model_attr='methodology')
    year = IntegerField(model_attr='year')
    name = CharField(model_attr='name')


class Graph(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    explanation = TextField(model_attr='explanation')
    type = CharField(model_attr='type')
    name = CharField(model_attr='name')

site.register(Researchers, ResearchersIndex)
site.register(Subject, SubjectIndex)
site.register(Research, ResearchIndex)
site.register(Graph, GraphIndex)
```

Thanks

Comment: you made the templates too?

Comment: yes, I did. I have 4 .txt files in templates/search/indexes/myproject/ corresponding to each class. also I have pasted from the tutorial from the site the template for searching, search.html and it is placed right under the search/ directory.

Comment: what haystack version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.2.7

Comment: your HAYSTACK_SITECONF is that or you change to put here?

Comment: no, that is that. because when I had **myproject.search_sites** it said "no module named search_sites".

Comment: so i think the problem is that the `search_sites` was not been called.

Comment: yes, that was it! please write it as a comment so I can choose it as an answer, and thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in your `HAYSTACK_SITECONF`. It must be the path to your `search_sites` file. Fix this and it should work.

Comment: This is no longer the right answer: if you try to use HAYSTACK_SITECONF you get a "don't do that" message.

Comment: This is the answer for the latest version in april 2013

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `site_indexes.py` is in an app that you have registered in the `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py